# "google-rich-snippets" instead of "rich-snippets"

Tags: discussion, retag-request

For [Google’s *Rich Snippets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#Rich_Snippets), we currently have the following tags:

- [google-rich-snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-rich-snippets) (<s>27</s> <s>57</s> 94)
- [rich-snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-snippets) (<s>138</s> <s>146</s> 172)

(<s>12</s> <s>20</s> 36 questions have [both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-rich-snippets+rich-snippets).)

**I propose to use only [google-rich-snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-rich-snippets).**

AFAIK the term was [coined by Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html), and while the term "rich snippets" *may* be used by some people even for other search engines, the current excerpt of [rich-snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-snippets) explicitly refers to Google: "[…] which appear under Google search results".

If questions about "rich snippets" (or whatever they may be called) from other search engines come up, they should get their own tag.

Comment: If `rich-snippets` is made a synonym, then independent use later on is that much harder; in that case just retag all those posts (138 isn't *that* much work).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, good point. But I’d still guess that we don’t need a general rich-snippets tag in the first place.